# What is the meaning when the expected value is equal to zero for a free particle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wave-particle-duality

> Let there be a free particle with mass $m$. 
>   At time $t=0$ it can be described as following wave packet:
>   $$ \psi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2a}} \Theta(a-|x|) $$
>   where $\Theta$ is the Heaviside step function and $a > 0$

The expected value is given by:
$$\langle x \rangle = \int x |\psi(x,t)|^2dx $$

The function is equal $1$ from $-a$ to $a$ and everywhere else its equal $0$. 
Therefore, the particle can only be found between $-a$ and $a$.

$$ \Rightarrow
\langle x \rangle  = \int_{-a}^{a} x |\psi(x)|^2dx = \frac{1}{2a} \int_{-a}^{a} x | \Theta(a-|x|)|^2dx
 = \frac{1}{2a} \int_{-a}^{a}xdx  = 0$$

However, now I am beginning to doubt my thought process, since I'm not sure what the expected value represents for the particle if its equal to zero. 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\langle x\rangle=0$, then if you take a bunch of position measurements of the particle in this state, the average of those measurements will be zero. This makes sense, since the wavefunction is evenly distributed around zero.